# Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

```js
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PublisherService{

    private publishersUrl = 'app/publisher';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getPublishers(): Promise<Publisher[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.publishersUrl)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(response => response.json().data) 
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable'.any

Comment: Normally, it's not a good idea to convert observables into promises. Observables are way more powerful

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles on this (it was the top google link for me), see the below which comes from one of the linked answers https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518#issuecomment-229506507 As it says, in Visual Studio 2015 you can fix this by updating your version of typescript via https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You need to add the operator like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

This is needed for every rxjs operator you want to use.

Comment: please update your answer for angular above version 2 (preferably 8 or 9)

Comment: toPromise is now marked as deprecated. use lastValueFrom instead.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding 'Response' to your import statement from '@angular/http'
like this :

```
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
```

Also i noticed you don't import Ingectable from angular core 
although you use @Injectable decorator.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: I have also updated the systemjs.config.js and followed the suggestions on this page. Now its fine.

Comment: hi MiHawk, what you did update in the systemjs.config.js?, I am also following the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html, got stuck here

Comment: So what was the answer, it isn't stated what fixes this issue

Comment: I installed the latest version of TypeScript tools version 2.X https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593 and this fixed the problem -- but created 209 others. The rest of the fix was to exit Visual Studio and run >npm upgrade --save (as admin). a couple of packages failed to update, but when I start Visual Studio Bower/npm automatically updated the rest and all is good.

Answer (score 5):

use this import at the beginning

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
```

Comment: really bad idea, this imports the entire RXJS library which is really big and will massively increase your page load times.

Comment: I don't think so.. we use import { component } from "@angular/core"; many places right so this should be also bad then ?

Comment: import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; is what you want ... this will import just Observable, if you do rxjs/Rx then it will import all of RxJS and only use the Observable, a real slow down. Remove all reference to rxjs/RX and watch the massive reduction in net requests and the speed up of page load speed.