# Why I am obtaining this error in an Angular application? Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am very new in **Angular2/4** and I have some problem trying to follow this tutorial related to **PrimeNG**:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

I created the **EventService** class into a file in my prohject, in this way:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getEvents() {
    return this.http.get('showcase/resources/data/scheduleevents.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
      .then(data => { return data; });
  }
}
```

The problem is that WebStorm give me an error on the **toPromise()** method, it says:

```
Error:(11, 8) TS2339:Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.
```

Why? What it means? What is the problem? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090989/property-topromise-does-not-exist-on-type-observableresponse)

Comment: The amount of time you put on writing this question, you could have perhaps just googled the error message and found an answer? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the operator like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```